# DirectX11 COM object with 0 references not released

Tags: com, directx-11, sharpdx

I'm trying to track down a "memory leak." However it's doesn't seem like a real memory leak since calling `ReportLiveDeviceObjects` reports that there are 0 references

```
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Texture2D at 0x00000140D3FE44F0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #425: LIVE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11RenderTargetView at 0x00000140D3FCBB60, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #428: LIVE_RENDERTARGETVIEW]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Texture2D at 0x00000140D3FE5BF0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #425: LIVE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11RenderTargetView at 0x00000140B8EDB000, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #428: LIVE_RENDERTARGETVIEW]
```

As you can see, the `ID3D11RenderTargetView` objects have both 0 internal and external references. However it's still a live object. What could cause this to happen?

For clarity, I am using this through SharpDX, though that shouldn't affect the debug output from DirectX 11.

Corresponding issue:
https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/issues/903

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DirectX 11 uses 'deferred destruction' of resources, so typically if you need to force destruction you need to `Flush`. For example, in [Direct3D game templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates), you need to fully unbind and destroy the render targets before resizing:

```
// Remove any bound render target or depth/stencil buffer
ID3D11RenderTargetView* nullViews [] = { nullptr }; 
m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(_countof(nullViews), nullViews, nullptr); 

// Destroy the views (which themselves hold the references to the resources)
m_renderTargetView.Reset(); 
m_depthStencilView.Reset(); 

// Flush the immediate context to force cleanup
m_d3dContext->Flush();
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I was calling flush, but before I disposed the render targets instead of after.