# How COM warning works? how does the device get initialized?

Tags: c++, com, direct3d, dxgi

My d3d11 c++ code produces warning for live COM objects that I never initialized.

my code:

```
#define _INCLUDE_LIBS__

#include "stdafx.h"

#define WINDOW_NAME L"main window"
#define WS WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{

    HWND hwnd = NULL; {

        WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 1));
        wc.hCursor = NULL;
        wc.hIcon = NULL;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wc.lpszClassName = L"MainClass";
        wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

        if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) OutputDebugString(L"ERROR  :   window class registration failed!");

        hwnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, WINDOW_NAME, WS, 0, 0, 1000, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

        if(!hwnd) OutputDebugString(L"ERROR  :   window Creation failed!");

    }

    IDXGIFactory1* factory = nullptr; {

        CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));
    }

    IDXGIAdapter* adapter = nullptr; {

        factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);

        DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC desc;

        adapter->GetDesc(&desc);

        OutputDebugString(L"\n");
        OutputDebugString(desc.Description);
        OutputDebugString(L"\n\n");

    }

    ID3D11Device* device = nullptr; ID3D11DeviceContext* context = nullptr; {

        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL lvl[] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0 };
        UINT flag = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;

        D3D11CreateDevice(adapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, NULL, flag, lvl, ARRAYSIZE(lvl), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, NULL, &context);

    }

    ID3D11Debug* debug = nullptr; {

        device->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debug));

    }


    if (context) context->Release();
    if (device) device->Release();
    if (adapter) adapter->Release();
    if (factory) factory->Release();

    debug->ReportLiveDeviceObjects(D3D11_RLDO_DETAIL);

    return 0;

}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this produces warning :

```
D3D11 WARNING: Live ID3D11Device at 0x0000020454692FF0, Refcount: 2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #441: LIVE_DEVICE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Context at 0x0000020454695020, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #2097226: LIVE_CONTEXT]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3DDeviceContextState at 0x000002045626F000, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #3145742: LIVE_DEVICECONTEXTSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11BlendState at 0x0000020456266170, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #435: LIVE_BLENDSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11DepthStencilState at 0x0000020456266370, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #436: LIVE_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11RasterizerState at 0x0000020456266570, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #437: LIVE_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Sampler at 0x0000020456266780, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #434: LIVE_SAMPLER]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Query at 0x0000020456266E60, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #438: LIVE_QUERY]
```

I dont't know why those extra objects like gets initialized. I did the release on the device twice and it seemed to work all fine again and I dont' know that happened either.

I would like to know if I made a mistake somewhere because I don't know how COM works internally even a little bit all i knew that I create the object, I release the object.

Yea and I have no idea why this happened, can somone please explain why this happens and what I should do to fix this?

I am using the visual studio community 2019, OS : Windows 64-bit

Comment: Never use COM like this (manually refcounting that is). Like C++ (std::shared_ptr) COM has a smart pointer type too.  [ATL::CComPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class?view=msvc-170). The extra COM objects may be created by directX internally and should disappear if you do your refcounting right. Also you seem to be missing calls to ::CoInitializeEx and ::CoUnitialize

Comment: Don't leak *debug*, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155133/directx11-com-object-with-0-references-not-released).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine (just don't forget to do `debug->Release` too).

The refcount = 0 lines are pretty useless, they are not leaks, and are here obviously created by internal D3D11 code (you don't create a blend state, etc.).

You can also use `D3D11_RLDO_DETAIL | D3D11_RLDO_IGNORE_INTERNAL` to get rid of some of these.

Now, using this API is notorious to show false positive, "on the edge". Experience shows its common to get 1 or 2 leaks on a device before quitting (probably some internal cache at play).
In general, you really want to worry when `ReportLiveDeviceObjects` results shows big numbers like you get 40 references to something while it should be 0, ie: this API is still useful.

However, when you work with COM objects, I strongly suggest you use any kind of smart pointers technology, there's [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class) `CComPtr` (with Visual Studio), [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) `com_ptr`, [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr) `com_ptr`, etc. this is the best way to avoid COM reference leaks.

For example, this code is 100% leak free (with ATL):

```
#include <atlbase.h>

CComPtr<IDXGIFactory> factory;
CreateDXGIFactory(IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory));

CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> adapter;
factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);
```